# Django : url connection to main page

Tags: django, url

I managed to login but I can not on the home page (mainView)

just "You're successfully logged in!"

what is the problem with mainView ?

url

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                     url(r'^$', main_page),
                     url(r'^$', mainView.as_view()),
```

views

```
def main_page(request):

    state = "Please log in below..."
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."

    return render_to_response('registration/main_page.html',{'state':state, 'username': username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

main_page.html

```
<form method="post" >
 {% csrf_token %}
    {% if next %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    {% endif %}
    username:
    <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username}}" /><br />
    password:
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

Comment: Since you have the same URL target, it would _always_ hit the first successful resolution.Try changing to `url(r'^home/$', mainView.as_view())`

Comment: I get the same thing with url(r'^home/$', mainView.as_view())..same page

Comment: well. you have to modify the code accordingly to redirect to the new url.. which is /home/

Comment: I have to modify the code in main_page ?

Comment: thanks ! it works. I just wrote : return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")